# The value of $|z|^2+|z−3|^2+|z−i|^2$ is minimum when $z$ equals?

Tags: complex-analysis, optimization, complex-numbers, analytic-geometry, triangles

> The value of $|z|^2+|z−3|^2+|z−i|^2$ is minimum when $z$ equals?

I thought probably the circumcentre of the triangle formed by $0,i,3$ should be the answer as in that case the distances would be equal.But the answer is different.Is there anyway to logically deduce the answer instead of the generic method that books follow (i.e. put $z=x+iy$ and then find minima).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @DeepSea mentioned, we can think of this problem geometrically. Given $\bigtriangleup ABC$, with $A=(0,0)$, $B=(3,0)$, $C=(0,1)$, find the point $P$ that minimizes $PA^2+PB^2+PC^2$.

I am first going to provide physical intuition, and then a rigorous proof as to why the point $P$ must be the centroid of the triangle.

Imagine three Hookean springs, all with spring-constant $1$. Attach one end of each spring to each vertex of the triangle. Take the other ends of the springs and attatch them to the same point, $X$. In this setup, the vertices are fixed, but point $X$ is free to move around. The potential energy of this system is proportional to $XA^2+XB^2+XC^2$. Since nature tends to minimize potential energy, when this system comes to rest, this quantity will be minimized. We also know that the system will come to rest when the net force is $0$. The net force for this system is proportional to the vector $\vec{XA}+\vec{XB}+\vec{XC}$. So, the system will come to rest when $\vec{XA}+\vec{XB}+\vec{XC}=0$. The only point with this property if the centroid, or $G=\displaystyle\frac{A+B+C}{3}$.

Now, for a rigorous proof from this site: http://www.cut-the-knot.org/triangle/medians.shtml (this is different from the one posted by @ArkyaChatterjee  in the comments)

Let's call the centroid $\displaystyle G=\frac{A+B+C}{3}$. It can be verified that $\vec{GA}+\vec{GB}+\vec{GC}=0$. Take any random point, $X$:
\begin{equation} \label{eq1}
\begin{split}
XA^2+XB^2+XC^2 & = \left|\vec{XA}\right|^2+\left|\vec{XB}\right|^2+\left|\vec{XC}\right|^2\\
 & = \left|\vec{GX}+\vec{GA}\right|^2+\left|\vec{GX}+\vec{GB}\right|^2+\left|\vec{GX}+\vec{GC}\right|^2\\
&= 3\left|\vec{GX}\right|^2+\left|\vec{GA}\right|^2+\left|\vec{GB}\right|^2+\left|\vec{GC}\right|^2+2\vec{GX}\cdot\left(\vec{GA}+\vec{GB}+\vec{GC}\right)\\
&= 3GX^2+GA^2+GB^2+GC^2+2\vec{GX}\cdot0\\
&= 3GX^2+GA^2+GB^2+GC^2\\
& \geq GA^2+GB^2+GC^2
\end{split}
\end{equation}
(Here, the operator $\cdot$ represents inner product.)

In your particular case, we have $\displaystyle z=\frac{0+3+i}{3}=1+\frac{i}{3}$.

Comment: I especially like the physical interpretation +1 !

Answer (score 4):

Let's try to generalize this problem. Suppose we have $n$ points $z_1,\ldots,z_n$ in the complex plane, and we wish to find the complex number $z$ which minimizes $\displaystyle\sum_{k = 1}^{n}|z-z_k|^2$.

Let $\mu = \dfrac{1}{n}\displaystyle\sum_{k = 1}^{n}z_k$ be the centroid of the points $z_1,\ldots,z_n$. Then,

$\displaystyle\sum_{k = 1}^{n}|z-z_k|^2$ $= \displaystyle\sum_{k = 1}^{n}(z-z_k)(\overline{z}-\overline{z}_k)$ $= \displaystyle\sum_{k = 1}^{n}(z\overline{z} - z_k\overline{z} - z\overline{z}_k + z_k\overline{z}_k)$

$= nz\overline{z} - \left(\displaystyle\sum_{k = 1}^{n}z_k\right)\overline{z} - z\left(\displaystyle\sum_{k = 1}^{n}\overline{z}_k\right) + \left(\displaystyle\sum_{k = 1}^{n}z_k\overline{z}_k\right)$ $= nz\overline{z} - n\mu\overline{z} - nz\overline{\mu} + \left(\displaystyle\sum_{k = 1}^{n}|z_k|^2\right)$

$= nz\overline{z} - n\mu\overline{z} - nz\overline{\mu} + n\mu\overline{\mu} - n\mu\overline{\mu} + \left(\displaystyle\sum_{k = 1}^{n}|z_k|^2\right)$ $= n(z-\mu)(\overline{z}-\overline{\mu}) - n\mu\overline{\mu} + \left(\displaystyle\sum_{k = 1}^{n}|z_k|^2\right)$

$= n|z-\mu|^2 - n\mu\overline{\mu} + \left(\displaystyle\sum_{k = 1}^{n}|z_k|^2\right)$

Clearly, $- n\mu\overline{\mu} + \left(\displaystyle\sum_{k = 1}^{n}|z_k|^2\right)$ is constant w.r.t. $z$ and $n|z-\mu|^2$ is minimized when $z = \mu$. Thus, $\displaystyle\sum_{k = 1}^{n}|z-z_k|^2$ is minimized when $z = \mu = \dfrac{1}{n}\displaystyle\sum_{k = 1}^{n}z_k$, i.e. when $z$ is the centroid of $z_1,\ldots,z_n$.

Answer (score 2):

The expression can be viewed as the sum of the square of the distances from $P = (x,y)$ to $3$ vertices of the triangle $\triangle ABC$ with $A = (0,0), B = (3,0), C = (0,1)$. This sum is minimized when $P$ coincides with the centroid which is the intersection of the medians.

Comment: How is $|z|^2$ the distance from vertices?Isn't it the square of distance from vertices?

Comment: @SanchayanDutta You are correct. However, the correct answer to this problem is the centroid of the triangle. The centroid does, indeed, minimize the sum of the squares of the distances from the vertices. The point that minimizes the sum of the distances from the vertices of a triangle is called the Fermat Point.

Comment: You might want to mention that you can calculate the centroid by taking the "average" of the coordinates. In other words, $$G=\frac{A+B+C}{3}$$

Comment: @Hrhm Can you give a proof as to why centroid minimizes sum of squares of distances?

Comment: @SanchayanDutta You can think of an intuitive argument for this in terms of moment of inertia. Moment of inertia of any system is the minimum when evaluated about its center of mass (centroid). Moment of inertia for a 3 particle system like this triangle would be proportional to the sum of squares of distances from the vertices. You can see why the centroid should be the correct answer. But then again, this is not a "proof" per se, but just an intuitive argument in favour of the result.

Comment: @ArkyaChatterjee That seems good.But still I'm not fully convinced...

Comment: @SanchayanDutta I'll try to type up an answer explaining why the centroid is the point that minimizes sum of squares of distances.

Comment: @SanchayanDutta You can also check out this proof 
 http://www.cut-the-knot.org/triangle/SumOfSquares.shtml

Comment: @ArkaChaterjee You can also use Hookean springs to explain why the centroid minimizes the sum of squares of distances. I will elaborate in my answer.

Comment: @SanchayanDutta: Are you looking for an algebraic proof as to why the centroid minimizes the sum of the squares of the distances, or some other kind of proof?

Comment: @JimmyK4542 Algebraic is preferable.But not that I would'nt like to know any other kind of proof...

Comment: @SanchayanDutta My response is finished, I hope it helps.

Comment: @Hrhm looking at "centroid", the first thing that comes to mind is center of mass, hence my intuitive explanation; yours is equally valid though.. cheers :D

Answer (score 1):

To elaborate on @DeepSea's answer: Given points $P_1, P_2, \ldots, P_k$ in euclidean space, let $\bar P:=\frac1k(P_1 +\cdots+P_k)$ be the average of the points (i.e., their centroid). To show that $\bar P$ is the point $Q$ that minimizes the sum of squared distances to the points $P_1,\ldots,P_k$, note that the squared distance from $Q$ to the $i$th point is
$$
\begin{align}
|Q-P_i|^2&=|Q-\bar P + \bar P-P_i|^2\\
&=|Q-\bar P|^2+\langle Q-\bar P,\bar P-P_i\rangle
+\langle\bar P-P_i,Q-\bar P\rangle+|\bar P-P_i|^2\tag1\end{align}
$$
where $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ denotes the inner product and $|Q|^2=\langle Q,Q\rangle$. When you sum (1) over all $i$, the second term drops out since
$$
\sum_i\langle Q-\bar P,\bar P-P_i\rangle=\langle Q-\bar P,\sum_i(\bar P-P_i)\rangle=\langle Q-\bar P,0\rangle=0.
$$
Similarly the third term drops out, so what remains is
$$
\sum_i|Q-P_i|^2=\sum_i|Q-\bar P|^2+\sum_i|\bar P-P_i|^2.\tag2
$$
Since the second term on the RHS of (2) is free of $Q$, it is clear that the sum of squared distances is minimized when $Q=\bar P$.

Answer (score 1):

- When $\text{z}\in\mathbb{C}$, we can write $z=a+bi$ where $a=\Re[z]$ and $b=\Im[z]$:
  $$\text{Q}(a,b)=|z|^2+|z−3|^2+|z−i|^2=10+3a(4-2)+b(3b-2)$$

To solve the minimum:

$$
\begin{cases}
\frac{\partial\text{Q}(a,b)}{\partial a}=3(a-2)+3a\\
\frac{\partial\text{Q}(a,b)}{\partial b}=6b-2
\end{cases}
$$

Solving this gives us $a=1$ and $b=\frac{1}{3}$